# For normal $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$ operator $T$ is injective iff its image is dense

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ a Hilbert space, $T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ is normal. 
Show that:

$T$ is injective iff $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ is dense in $H$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Edit: Normal was not in the previous hypothesis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should go as follows.

For any operator $T \in \mathcal{B}(H)$ one has that $\ker T^* = (\mathrm{Im} T)^{\perp}$.
This implies that $\ker T = \ker T^*T$ because restricted to the image of $T$, $T^*$ is injective. But now since the operator $T$ is normal you get
$$ \ker T  = \ker T^*T = \ker TT^* = \ker T^* = (\mathrm{Im} T)^{\perp}.$$

Now it follows that $T$ is injective if and only if the orthogonal complement of the image is trivial, which says that $T$ has dense image.

Comment: Why is $T^*$ injective on $Im T$?

Answer (score 1):

This is answer to the original question when normality of $T$ were not assumed.

This is not true, consider right shift on $\ell_2$.

It is even isometric but its image is not dense in $H$, it is of codimension $1$ in $H$.

Comment: My mistake, I Missed a hypothesis.

Comment: @P.M.O. Did you mean Norbert?

Comment: Yes Matt N. Sorry